# Vue.js SPA redirecting to index.html with .htaccess does not work for every Page

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, redirect, vue-component, vue-router

I have created my Website with Vue3 and I am Using Vue router to navigate in my Application. I published my Website and added the following .htaccess to redirect all requests to index.html. It works for a few "pages" but not for all of them. For example if you try this link

`https://senph-design.de/about`

it just works fine, but if you try the following link

`https://senph-design.de/branding`

it will show the 404 not found page, and I don't know what I'm missing in my .htaccess file.

What I noticed is that it isn't working for every page I used a component in it but I don't know how to fix this problem.

**this is my .htaccess code**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(.png|.jpg|.gif|.jpeg|.bmp)$
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

**And this ist my index.js for the Vue Router**

```
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Welcome",
    component: Welcome,
  },
  {
    path: "/branding",
    name: "Branding",
    component: Branding,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    component: About,
  },
  {
    path: "/ux",
    name: "Ux",
    component: Ux,
  },
  {
    path: "/spielwiese",
    name: "Spielwiese",
    component: Spielwiese,
  },
  {
    path: "/kontakt",
    name: "Kontakt",
    component: Kontakt,
  },
  {
    path: "/impressum",
    name: "Impressum",
    component: Impressum,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 };
  },
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Do you have a `branding` directory in your public folder that apache is trying to access?

Comment: Oh yes i have stored all pictures in folder with the same names as the route, never would have thought that this might be the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this config in your .htaccess file and replace  with your application url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase <BASE URL>
   RewriteRule ^<BASE URL>/index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . <BASE URL>/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If i use this in my .htaccess file it results in an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Make sure that the publicPath is set to / in production mode in your `vue.config.js` file like this 
`export default {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/' : '/local-dev-path',
}`